# Complication error for Huawei analytics dependency

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I added the Huawei Analytics dependency implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:5.0.5.301'.
With this dependency I'm getting the following error at runtime. Any idea/help?

com.supremetech.signal E/PA_HuaweiIAPHelper: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/huawei/hms/utils/a;

```
    at com.huawei.hms.support.api.iap.json.Iap.getIapClient(Iap.java:26)
    at com.supremetech.signal.iap.HuaweiIAPProxy.checkIAPSupport(HuaweiIAPProxy.java:109)
    at com.supremetech.signal.Signal.retrieveIAPLicensesSync(Signal.java:5452)
    at com.supremetech.signal.Signal.access$3100(Signal.java:180)
    at com.supremetech.signal.Signal$23.run(Signal.java:5436)
    at com.supremetech.signal.tools.ThreadHelper$1.run(ThreadHelper.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.huawei.hms.utils.a" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.supremetech.signal-8yBhTRXpYmWEJDsjak6Bgw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.supremetech.signal-8yBhTRXpYmWEJDsjak6Bgw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.supremetech.signal-8yBhTRXpYmWEJDsjak6Bgw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.huawei.hms.support.api.iap.json.Iap.getIapClient(Iap.java:26) 
    at com.supremetech.signal.iap.HuaweiIAPProxy.checkIAPSupport(HuaweiIAPProxy.java:109) 
    at com.supremetech.signal.Signal.retrieveIAPLicensesSync(Signal.java:5452) 
    at com.supremetech.signal.Signal.access$3100(Signal.java:180) 
    at com.supremetech.signal.Signal$23.run(Signal.java:5436) 
    at com.supremetech.signal.tools.ThreadHelper$1.run(ThreadHelper.java:150) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

Answer (score 1):

@[Zinna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357441/zinna)'s answer is correct, but I'd like to add a little more:

The latest IAP version number is `implementation 'com.huawei.hms:iap:5.1.0.300'`

you need to add build dependencies in the dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.huawei.hms:iap:5.1.0.300'
}
```

For details,pls kindly refer this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001050035023?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Thank you for your concerns and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From above java exception log, it indicates that your IAP version is too old, that’s why you are encountering this issue. Please double check your IAP version and make sure they match the latest version 5.0.1.300.

Add IAP dependency to Gradle file: implementation 'com.huawei.hms:iap: 5.0.1.300, this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried with latest version and worked well.